# new Nexentastor installation - can't run bonnie

Tags: zfs, nexenta

I am new to Nexenta but so far I am liking it. I want to use it to replace Freenas for the ZFS advancements.

Anyways I am noticing sort of bad performance with CIFS (30-50MB/s) so I figured I would run some Bonnie tests.

but bonnie gives me the following error:

`nmc@nyx:/Data1$ run benchmark bonnie-benchmark
Volume 'Data1' is the only available volume, starting benchmark...
Data1: running optimal mode benchmark
Data1: generating 4094MB files, using 32768 blocks
chown: cannot access Data1/.nmc-bonnie-benchmark: No such file or directory`

I do have a pool and then I created a folder inside the pool. I setup Cifs and my one server that I created can access the share and upload files just fine.

Any ideas?

the specs of the server (in case you have ideas on the speed issue without the benchmarks):
Core2Duo E6600
2GB of ram (going to go to 6GB as soon)
Asus P5Q WS workstation board
6x Seagate 1.5TB SATAII drives, Bios/ICH set to AHCI or whatever it is (getting late!) so no raid is set, just single disks.

I created a single Raidz pool with all 6 disks.

No l2Arc or ZIL (this is just a personal home fileserver)

thanks.

Luma

Edit1: Benchmark results: using no options/flags.

Version 1.03b       ------Sequential Output------ --Sequential Input- --Random-
                    -Per Chr- --Block-- -Rewrite- -Per Chr- --Block-- --Seeks--
Machine        Size K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP  /sec %CP
nyx              4G 121285  53 135904  32 93036  28 131643  89 502117  65 298.3                                                    2
                    ------Sequential Create------ --------Random Create--------
                    -Create-- --Read--- -Delete-- -Create-- --Read--- -Delete--
              files  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP
                 16 21914  99 +++++ +++ +++++ +++ 19762  98 +++++ +++ +++++ +++
nyx,4G,121285,53,135904,32,93036,28,131643,89,502117,65,298.3,2,16,21914,99,++++                                                 +,+++,+++++,+++,19762,98,+++++,+++,+++++,+++

Here is a second benchmark using the command you provided:

Version 1.03b       ------Sequential Output------ --Sequential Input- --Random-
                    -Per Chr- --Block-- -Rewrite- -Per Chr- --Block-- --Seeks--
Machine        Size K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP  /sec %CP
nyx              4G 174009  73 237713  48 149055  41 141245  94 537932  58 489.6   1
                    ------Sequential Create------ --------Random Create--------
                    -Create-- --Read--- -Delete-- -Create-- --Read--- -Delete--
files:max:min        /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP
    64:100000:16/64  5094  57   783   7 39774  98  5950  50   142   1 21524  77
nyx,4G,174009,73,237713,48,149055,41,141245,94,537932,58,489.6,1,64:100000:16/64,5094,57,783,7,39774,98,5950,50,142,1,21524,77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd run the bonnie++ benchmark from the command line without the Nexenta wrapper.

First, you'll need to log in as the root user and get into the full command shell mode using:

`option expert_mode = 1` followed by `!bash`

Answer `y` the prompt that says `You are about to enter the Unix ("raw") shell and execute low-level Unix command(s).`

From here, you can download and install the proper bonnie++ executable.

```
# Update the apt package database
root@nyx:/volumes# apt-get update

# Install bonnie++
root@nyx:/volumes# apt-get install bonnie++

# Change to the target directory
root@nyx:/volumes# cd /volumes/Data1/your.cifs.folder
```

At this point, you can run a bonnie benchmark with or without parameters.

I usually run `bonnie++ -u root -n 64:100000:16:64`, but you'll be fine running `bonnie++ -u root` inside of the directory you wish to work in.

Post your results. There are a few tweaks needed for Nexenta when used without SAS or SCSI disks. You should at least see 80-90MB/s sequential write speed to a RAIDZ array. Read speed should be better than that.

Comment: Excellent Answer! thank you. I will do this now and post my results as an edit to my main post.

Comment: Here is a regular benchmark (no extra options/flags)

Comment: When I enabled Jumbo frames on the Nexenta machine and then also on my desktop (Switch already had them enabled) I suddenly started getting near-gigabit speeds (900-950megabits to and from the nexentastore (using cifs) so that is perfetly fine with me! now I did notice some strange things with Nexenta but I think its because I am running it from usb stick (for testing, will rectify that!)